# Killing a QThread in PySide when GUI is destroyed

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside, qthread

I am creating a slider bar that "warps" values based on how far it is dragged from the center point. I want to do it correctly by using treads to do the warping. Here is my thread for the actual timing stuff:

```
class WarpThread(QtCore.QThread):
    errorHappened = False

    # This will be a semaphore used to wake up the warper thead when the slider
    # is being manipulated. It starts at 0. Upon sliderPressed, it is set to +1.
    # when the slider is released, it is set -1 again. The thread then will
    # wait on the semiphore till it is > 0. When it is, it steps up our value,
    # sleeps and then waits again
    doWarp = None

    updateWarp = Signal()
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(WarpThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.exiting = False
        self.doWarp = QtCore.QSemaphore(0)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.doWarp.acquire()
            if self.exiting:
                break
            self.updateWarp.emit()
            self.doWarp.release()
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(50)

    # === External function calls ===
    def startWarping(self):
        self.doWarp.release() # Allow the thread to start looping

    def stopWarping(self):
        self.doWarp.acquire()

    def stopThread(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.doWarp.release()
        self.wait()
```

So the Warp Slider just calls `startWarping` when the signal `sliderPressed` is received and `stopWarping` when `sliderReleased` is received. That all works great. The plan was to call `stopThread` inside `__del__` of the thing that has the slider. Well, when I close out of the GUI without doing anything, it closes fine. When I exit after using the slider, I get a `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` error. I tried making the thread not be a parent of the one with the slider (thinking Qt might be destroying it through the inheritance tree,) but that didn't seem to do anything. So I guess I don't understand when the thread is being destroyed.

Does Qt destroy the objects not in the overall parent-child tree of the x-ed out GUI?
Why doesn't stopping the thread in `__del__` of the widget using the thread seem to work?
Why does it only have a problem after using stuff?

If you have useful links, please leave them in the comments. I have had a hard time finding an answer partially because I lack the vocab to search effectively

**EDIT**

Also, I know some suggest just making the threads global to ensure they don't get killed, but there is one thread for every slider... Maybe that's the point of design that needs to change... to be continued.

Comment: Or perhaps: Is there some way to tell the threads to just terminate when the gui does? The final close of these threads doesn't need to be graceful.

Comment: Seems to me that you acquire the semaphore in stopWarping, and then again in run, which is why you have a deadlock - it's not a problem with thread shutdown. This only happens if stopWarping gets called, i.e., after the slider is released.

Comment: @mdurant The slider works fine. That part has been tested and has no problems. The semaphore, in this case, is used backwards. When I want the loop to run, I add 1 to the semaphore (release) so that the acquire in the loop can unblock. When I want to stop looping I call the acquire (-1) so that the acquire in the loop will start blocking again. When killing the thread, I set exiting to true and then again unblock the loop with release().
The only problem I have with this is when the program closes. I don't like having the ugly error in the command line every time I quit.

Comment: @mdurant If I didn't block the loop when the slider was not being used, I would be wasting a lot of cpu power.

Comment: Are you certain, then, that the break in run actually happens? Does stopThread complete or get stuck at wait?

Comment: @mdurant Ok, I found the problem. There was an exception that was being masked. This meant that part of the program was dying while the threads were still running. The code that called `stopThread` was never getting called because of the exception. I think I need a better practice when using exceptions. Thanks for taking a look, though. I should have posted more of the code. My bad.

Comment: If you have a useful solution, you may consider answering your own question.

Comment: @mdurant I don't know if I have a real answer. Python throws exceptions for NoneType bugs and stuff. I think the real solution is just coding in an exception-safe way. I have no good answers for that. Exceptions, to me, almost seem like `goto` statements. They can be dangerous in the way they skip over code. Overall, I think I just need to be more vigilant and relearn the basics of exception handling.